# How not to return a mutable from a method and exposing class internals

Tags: c#, immutability

I think that is a commonly asked question and I believe I have covered the bases well, as in how objects, structs or value types are passed between functions. Let us assume I have the following classes:

```
public class User{
    public int xCoor{get;set}
    public int yCoor{get;set}
}

public class UserManager{
    Dictionary<int,User> userMapping = new  Dictionary<int,User>();
    public void AddUser(User user){//stuff}
    public void RemoveUser(User user){//stuff}
    public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers(){return userMapping.Values;}
}

public class UserConsumer{
    private UserManager;
    public void GetUserCoordinates(){
        var listThatExposesInternals = UserManager.GetAllUsers().ToList();
        listThatExposesInternals.Foreach(user => user.xCoor = user.yCoor = 0);
    // Now that I altered the internals of the class, it is messed up
    // I only want the consumer to be able read
    }
}
```

How can I make sure that the internals of the User class stays intact. I am aware that for this problem it is also appropriate to expose xCoor and yCoor rather than the whole User class but most of the time I face the problem (need?) to return the reference to the class. I appreciate any advises.

Comment: If you don't want people to be able to mutate an object, don't make the object mutable...

Comment: Ask your self this: who should be able to modify `User`'s `xCoor` and `yCoor`?

Comment: @Servy, thank you very much for your time answering. The thing is sometimes I require User class to be mutated in some part of the framework and in other parts it needs to be immutable and used only for looking at it s values.

Comment: @Andrew UserManager only can modify User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of approaches you could take. If there is never a situation where `xCoor` and `yCoor` should be changed after `User` is instantiated, you could require the values in its constructor and make the setter `private` to ensure they can't be changed outside this class.

```
public class User
{

    public User(int xCoor, int yCoor)
    {
        this.xCoor = xCoor;
        this.yCoor = yCoor;
    }

    public int xCoor{get; private set;}
    public int yCoor{get; private set;}
}
```

If you do need `User` to be mutable, but want to discourage changing the properties under certain circumstances, you could create an interface for `User` to implement that only has getters on those properties. However, people could still cast their `IReadableUser` as a `User` and access those properties.

Another option would be to create a new class that wraps a `User` object, and only exposes getters which read the properties from an actual `User` instance, but cannot set those same properties. This option could be combined with the `IReadableUser` approach above, to hide the implementation details of the returned object while still preventing people from casting the object to a `User` to change its values.

```
public interface IReadOnlyUser
{
    int xCoor {get;}
    int yCoor {get;}
}

internal class ReadOnlyUser : IReadOnlyUser
{
    private readonly User user;

    public ReadOnlyUser(User user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public int xCoor{get { return this.user.xCoor; }}
    public int yCoor{get { return this.user.yCoor; }}
}

public IEnumerable<IReadOnlyUser> GetAllUsers()
{
    return userMapping.Values
        .Select(u => (IReadOnlyUser) new ReadOnlyUser(u));
}
```

Yet another option would be to *allow* the users to mutate the values you return, but ensure these values are copied values so the next time someone asks for the list of users they're seeing instances that haven't been changed.

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
{
    return userMapping.Values
        .Select(u => new User { xCoor = u.xCoor, yCoor = u.yCoor });
}
```

If you had more reference-based values in your `User` class, your `Select` statement would need to create new instances of those as well. If that becomes burdensome, you might consider giving each class a copy constructor to ensure that the responsibility for copying values is consolidated into the part of code where it's most likely to be noticed and fixed when things change.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time answering. I thought about the Interface, IReadableUser, but like you mentioned it can easily be cast into User and access again into internals. This becomes especially problematic when Use class has some properties as objects.

Comment: @EmrahSüngü: You can use a wrapper class to protect against that. The wrapper class can either be used directly, or implement an interface as shown in my updated code sample.

Comment: Thanks for a very detailed explanation. What if one of the properties that I would like to expose is not a primitive type (int in this case) but another object (for example Address class with some other sub-properties). How do you suggest I should go around that problem?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü: Values like `Address` would also need to be wrapped in a read-only class.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for marking this as an answer. Lost my previous account and am not having enough reputation to post this as a comment (not yet).

One way to do it is to make all the Properties readOnly and set the values through the constructor. However, I am not sure if that works for you. If the behavior of class modifies the state of object, then that may throw a wrench in the wheel.

About the List, if the list returns a copy of the object (i.e. returns the copy of the List) then that should be good. If you want the individual objects to be not mutable, you have 2 options

1. Make copy of individual data containers (objects) instead of just copying the references (which this one does)
2. Force the data container to be non-mutable by exposing the properties as get only and make the setters as private.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe removing the sets or making them private :

```
public class User{
    public int xCoor{get;}
    public int yCoor{get;}
}
```

or

```
public class User{
    public int xCoor{get; private set;}
    public int yCoor{get; private set;}
}
```

Comment: You also need to provide a constructor or they will have no way to set the properties at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways. I am suspecting that you merely need to remove the "set" from each set/get.

you could have:

```
public class User
{
    protected int _xCoor = 0;
    protected int _yCoor = 0;

    public int xCoor
    {
        get { return _xCoor; }
    }

    public int yCoor
    {
        get { return _yCoor; }
    }
}
```

In my example case, in order to change the values of _xCoor and _yCoor, you would have to created a class that inherits from the User class.

Comment: If `code User` class has some properties as objects then I will be able to change the underlying object, right?

Comment: yes, you are correct; however, if you create a class that inherits from User, you could place the functions that will change the values in there. Then you have a choice to expose the User class (nothing can be set) or the class that inherits from User that has public functions (can set things).